# Iron Python installed but project type missing from VS08

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ironpython

I installed IronPython.msi from Codeplex (http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=8365) and expected to see an entry for IronPython in VS08 (professional) when I go to create a new project but it is not listed.

Where and what does this install add to my system?

Am I missing something?

C

Answer (score 2):

Try installing [IronPython Studio](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPythonStudio). Be careful - it seems to use an older version of IronPython.

Answer (score 1):

IronPython does not have any VS Integration. The link in your question simply installs the commandline tool. The default folder is IronPython 2.0 under ProgramFiles. That is the only thing that gets installed on your machine.

I'm not sure if IronPython Studio that @gimel points supports IPy 2.0 - probably not.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of IronPython ([2.7 Beta 1](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/48818), as of this writing) includes support for Visual Studio 2010, but not earlier editions.